# RDP Session with same account

Tags: windows, rdp, mstsc

**Here is my situation:**

I have a Windows 8.1 where a local account is always connected (no time out configured by GPO).

My goal is to open a `RDP` session remotely with `mstsc` and with this specific account. So we will recover our session remotely.

**My constraints are:**

I don't want any popup to allow the `RDP` session, because this is a bot session locally.
I absolutely need that when we disconnect from the `RDP` session, the local session have to stay open (no lock).

How can I proceed to respect my constraints?

Answer (score 1):

Install hyper-v on the server you are running this client on and use the hyper-v console to connect rather than RDP.  If your "bot" is requiring a GUI, you have other fish to fry on the app side.